# Skip Not-registred Number Whatsapp Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

im using Selenium and Python to create a Whatsapp Bot to read number and name from xlsx file and send specific message!

started by webdriver.
open web.whatsapp.com and use parameters from excel file to send a message.

Code is HERE :

```
def readContacts(fileName):
    delay = 30
    f = open("message.txt",  encoding='utf-8')
    ads = f.read()
    f.close()
    ads = quote(ads)
    lst = []
    file = excel.load_workbook(fileName)
    sheet = file.active
    firstCol = sheet['A']
    secondCol = sheet['B']
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
    time.sleep(1)


    for cell in range(len(firstCol)):
        contact = str(firstCol[cell].value)
        message = str(secondCol[cell].value)
        link = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+ contact +"&text="+ message + ' عزیز ' + '%0A ' + ads
        driver.get(link)
        print("Sending message to", contact)

        
        
        try:
            click_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME , '_4sWnG')))
            click_btn.click() 
            sleep(5)
            print("Message sent successfuly")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            
            print("Failed to send message")

    driver.quit()


targets = readContacts("./contact.xlsx")
```

now i have numbers in excel file that are not member of whatsapp.

how can i skip this number?